# Spring Cloud Data Flow preconfigured tasks

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

Spring Cloud Data Flow is a great solution and currently I'm trying to find the possibility to preconfigure the tasks in order to trigger them manually.
The use-case very simple:

- as a DevOps I should have ability to preconfigure the tasks, which includes creation of the execution graph and application and deploy parameters and save task with all parameters needed for execution.
- as a User with role ROLE_DEPLOY I should have ability start, stop, restart and execution monitor the preconfigured tasks.

Preconfigured tasks is the task with all parameters needed for execution.

Is it possible to have such functionality?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to review the continuous deployment section from the [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_task_launch_lifecycle). There's built-in lifecycle semantics for orchestrating tasks in SCDF.

Assuming you have the Task applications already built and that the DevOps persona is familiar with how the applications work together, they can either interactively or programmatically build a [composed-task definition](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_composed_tasks_dsl) and task/job parameters in SCDF.

The above step persists the task definition in the SCDF's database. Now, the same definition can be launched manually or via a cronjob schedule.

If nothing really changes to the definition, app version, or the task/parameters, yes, anyone with the `ROLE_DEPLOY` role can interact with it.

You may also find the [CD for Tasks](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/batch-developer-guides/continuous-deployment/cd-basics/) guide useful reference material. Perhaps repeat this locally (with desired security configurations) on your environment to get a hold of how it works.